# inserting java values to sqlite database

Tags: java, database, connection

This is a java inserting values to database problem.

I want to insert data into my database but I get an exception that states "Query does not return results". What am I doing wrong? What should I return?

This is my function code:

```
public void commitToDB(String fName) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname)" + " VALUES (?)";
    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, fName);

        // execute the preparedstatement
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Got an exception");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());           
    }
    finally {
        preparedStatement.close();
        resultSet.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: resultset is only needed if you have a select query. if its update/insert etc, you dont have to assign it to a resultset. what can come back from the method is an int if i remember correctly. this int only shows if it was successful or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wan to execute an update statement (Something that doesn't return a ResultSet) but you are trying to execute it as a query. I made this mistake too when I was working with a database driver in Java for the first time.

What you want to do is change:

```
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

to this:

```
preparedStatement.execute();
```

Comment: yup, that was it. Although I changed execute() to executeUpdate() instead. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

executeQuery works for select statements
for insert/update you should use executeUpdate. This methods returns int (record count that were inserted/updated)